# Ubuntu Netbook Edition and automatic login

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, login

I'm trying to set up the automatic login, but i can't choose the user which must be loged in. Here a screenshot (German is set as default language):

[image: Ubuntu Netbook Edition automatic login]

any suggestion, how to solve the problem?

I'm using UNE 10.10, upgraded from 10.04...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that i can't use the automatic login, because my home folder is encrypted.

```
* (gdmsetup:2834): WARNING: Unable to lookup user name data: Success *
* (gdmsetup:2834): DEBUG: XXXXXX XXXXX is using an encrypted home, not listing him for autologin *
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you logging in as "root" by any chance (AFAIK "root" gets removed from that drop-down list)?

Anyways, you can add the information to the '[daemon]' section of the file '/etc/gdm/custom.conf':

```
...
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=<USERNAME>
...
```

Comment: i'm not logged in as root, but my user is in the sudoers list. In the custom.conf was the entry for AutomaticLogin empty...i've added it manually and will try it right now :)

Comment: Do you see any suspicious messages when running 'gdmsetup' from the terminal?

Comment: yes :) ****** ** (gdmsetup:2834): WARNING **: Unable to lookup user name data: Success
** (gdmsetup:2834): DEBUG: XXXXXX XXXXX is using an encrypted home, not listing him for autologin ******

Comment: !:-) Good to know.

Comment: that is not good :) why should be disabled the automatic login, if i've encrypted my home?

Comment: I don't know if there are technical reasons, but one question comes to my mind: why would you encrypt your home folder if you grant access to everyone that can access the machine?

Comment: I'm using the netbook most of the time at home and only for holiday away...so, for the case, that i'm on holiday, i want to disable the automatic login, but for home is that not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A "*dirty*" init script with a automated login, password and a decrypt should be coded?

I am not a programmer, so I don't know if it's possible. I think about something you can just turn on/off with a single reboot to go "*holiday*" mode or "*inhome*" mode. (put/delete the script to automatically run on boot, even a script to do this too, a button on dock)

The 1st script will do the autologin and the decrypt for you when in "*inhome*" mode.

Sure you gonna search a good way to store the password for the script.

Answer (score -1):

Go to **Applications**, next go to **Users and Groups** click on the user and your going to have to put in the root password to unlock then click passwords and check the **do not ask at log in**.

Comment: doesn't work, becaus nautilus try to access/read/write in some files or folders under ${HOME}....without password is not possible to access this files/folders, so the login doesn't work correct.

Comment: It's in system menu and not applications.