# Not able to automatically login

Tags: login

Hey I'd like to login automatically, but havnt gotten the option to do so.
I have tried some hints and stuff
But nothing has worked so far.
Im running 12.10 and have xbmc installed(dont know if it matters, the xbmc).
Here is 2 screenshots of how my settings look.

[image: config file]
the last 2 lines i have put in myself. (har restarted after, didnt work and below you see user accounts settings, from after reboot)

[image: useraccounts settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it won't work if you home directory is encrypted.

[Unencrypt Home Directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107410/can-you-unencrypt-remove-encryption-from-a-user-home-folder)

[Autologin disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11240/why-is-the-automatic-login-disabled-for-users-with-encrypted-home)

Comment: Can I unencrypt it? cant remember if I haven chosen to encrypt it in anyway :/

Comment: @AndersMetnik see update answer.  I am 100% that encryption doesn't allow you to autologin.  You may want to verify it before you do this.

Comment: @AndersMetnik I just looked it up.  It is due to having an encrypted home dir.