# Ubuntu 14.10 Auto Login

Tags: 14.10, auto-login

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 from 14.04 LTS about a month ago. I have my computer encrypted already, so I have to put a password in when starting up my computer. But I also have to login each and every time. This seems redundant to me. How can I make my computer auto login?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/11240/why-is-the-automatic-login-disabled-for-users-with-encrypted-home Automatic login and encryption are a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "I have my computer encrypted already"?

If you configured ubuntu to encrypt your home directory, then the comment from @Rinzwind is correct and you cannot set auto-login for this user.

However, if you are referring to some other encryption strategy, it should be possible to configure auto-login from the usual way:

1. Go to *User Accounts* and select the user in question.
2. Switch the *Automatic Login* field to the ON position.

Comment: I guess it means he wants to skip login because no one but him has the password for the encrypted boot disk anyway. I'm looking for the same solution since I'm the only one who ever uses this disk-encrypted Ubuntu VM.